# Problema a la hora de mandar un rango de fechas php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos input que le pasa un rango de fechas al programa en php que me tiene que devolver unos ids, el problema está en que no me devuelve nada, todo en blanco:

```
Desde Fecha <input name="desde_fecha_cumple" type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>"/><br />
Hasta fecha <input name="hasta_fecha_cumple" type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>"/><br />
```

Estos son los inputs, y el programa en php:

```
function ids_cumplen_anos($fecha) {
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "XX", "XXX");
  mysql_select_db("XX_database", $link);
  $sql = "select id from usuario where day(FechaNacimiento)>=day('" . $fecha . "') and month(FechaNacimiento)>=month('" . $fecha . "') AND day(FechaNacimiento)<=day('" . $fecha ."') and month(FechaNacimiento)<=month('" . $fecha ."')"; //funcion sacar cumple
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
  $socios = array();
  if ($result) {
    //echo "hay resultados";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $socios[] = $row['id'];
    }
  }
  if (!count($socios))
    $socios = 0;

  return $socios;
}
```

Esto tiene que generar un excel con el siguiente codigo:

```
"datos" => obtener_socios(ids_cumplen_anos($datos['desde_fecha_cumple'], $datos['hasta_fecha_cumple'], $datos['opt']));
```

Como puedo hacer el rango de fechas para que se pasen ambas al programa en php y este me lo imprima en el excel?

---

He realizado un echo de $sql y unicamente me devuelve una fecha

En el primer input le indico `02/03/2017` y en el segundo input `04/04/2017`

Esta es la consulta:

> select id from usuario where day(FechaNacimiento)>=day('2017-03-02')
>   and month(FechaNacimiento)>=month('2017-03-02') and
>   day(FechaNacimiento)<=day('2017-03-02') and
>   month(FechaNacimiento)<=month ('2017-03-02')

El mismo primer valor del primer input en todas, no coge el segundo valor del segundo input.

Edit2-- Ya me coge ambos valores de las fechas pero no me pinta los ids de los socios que cumplen años entre ese rango.

Comment: Te recomiendo lo siguiente, imprime tu variable `$sql` y muestra cómo estás armando la instrucción SQL, pega esa instrucción en MySQL y ejecútala, observa si tiene errores de sintaxis u otro error. Si devuleve datos, entonces revisa el código PHP. **[edit] tu pregunta con los resultados obtenidos**.

Comment: lo acabo de hacer y unicamente me esta cogiendo una fecha, lo cual no entiendo, porque marco por ejemplo en el desde 01/03/2017 y en el hasta 04/04/2017 (ayer) y solo me coge la primera

Comment: actualiza tu pregunta con la consulta obtenida y valores de los inputs.

Comment: añadido, gracias

Answer (score 2):

Buenas la consulta lo haría de la siguiente manera para obtener datos según rango de fechas.

```
SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE FechaNacimiento BETWEEN '2017-03-02' and '2017-
03-04';
```

Si estás enviando una cadena con el formato '%d/%m/%Y' necesitas convertirlo y formatearlo para que de esa manera obtengas los usuarios que cumplen años según el rango de fechas que indicaste.

```
SELECT id  FROM usuario 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(FechaNacimiento, '%m/%d'), '%m/%d')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('02/03/2017', '%d/%m')
AND STR_TO_DATE('04/03/2017', '%d/%m')
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hola para que te trabaje el rango de fecha, tienes que colocar dos fechas distinta. Por lo que estas mostrando en tu código son iguales ya que estas usando el método **date** de php en los dos campos. Te dejo unos ejemplos:

> Obtener todas las las personas que nacieron un día en especifico:

select id from usuario where FechaNacimiento = '2000-05-04';

> Obtener todas las personas que estén comprendida entre 2000-05-04 y 2017-04-05

```
select id from usuario where FechaNacimiento >= '2000-05-04' AND FechaNacimiento <= '2017-04-05'
```

Comment: buenas, pero yo lo que necesitaria es que se pasaran desde los inputs, quiero decir pongo en un input 2014-03-03 y en otro input 2014-03-05 y que me muestre en este caso los cumpleaños desde el 03 al 05, seria igual?

Comment: Lo puedes hacer así **select id from usuario where FechaNacimiento >= '2014-03-03' AND FechaNacimiento <= '2014-03-05'**  esto lo que que quiere decir es que que te va traer todas las fechas mayores iguales que 2014-03-03 y menores iguales que 2014-03-05

Comment: ya he solucionado lo de las fechas, me devuelve ambos valores, el problema ahora que no me saca los datos que le pido que me saque, me tendria que sacar los socios que cumplen años entre ese rango y no me lo saca..

Comment: Verifica que para este rango de fecha, que tu me mandaste tengas valores en tu campo de  **FechaNacimiento**.  Lo otro que te recomiendo es que pruebes, la consulta aparte para que veas que si te esta devolviendo los datos. Esto lo puedes hacer con phpmyadmin sino tienes cliente mysql

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que a tu función le estas pasando solo una fecha y entonces estas buscando los parámetros de una sola fecha., tendrías que pasarle las dos fechas.
Por ejemplo:

```
function ids_cumplen_anos($fecha1,fecha2) {
  $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "XX", "XXX");
  mysql_select_db("XX_database", $link);
  $sql = "select id from usuarios where FechaNacimiento between '".$fecha1."' and '".$fecha2."'"; //funcion sacar cumple
  $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
  $socios = array();
  if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
    //echo "hay resultados";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $socios[] = $row['id'];
    }
  }
  else{
$socios = 0;
}

  return $socios;
}
```

PD: No hay necesidad de castear la fecha a días, meses o años, a menos que necesites otro tipo de información. 
Blasito tiene razón, tienes que ver que el formato que estas mandando corresponde al almacenado en la DB, si es diferente hay que castearlo.

Saludos

Comment: he realizado lo de la fecha y sí, me coge ambos valores (los valores en la base de datos esta como Y/m/d y desde el input ya se lo mando como Y/m/d por lo que no habría que castearlo); Pero no me pinta los ids de los socios que cumplen años en ese rango de fechas.

Comment: No entiendo como quieres que te los pinte. has un echo de $sql y ejecuta esa misma consulta en la consola de mysql. Si no te regresa nada es problema de la DB o la consulta. Si te regresa IDs entonces estas pintando mal el array. Puedo ver como lo estas intentando pintar?

Comment: Acabo de realizar la siguiente consulta a la base de datos:
SELECT id FROM usuario WHERE fechanacimiento BETWEEN  '2014-10-10' AND  '2015-01-05'; esto me ha devuelto unos valores, por lo que descarto que sea problema de la consulta, el array mal no está dado que otras funciones que tiran de base de datos y del array, funcionan perfectamente, ya no se si es el if el que esta mal o ya no lo sé

Comment: Mira, prueba así, quite el IF de abajo y le puse un else en su lugar

Comment: Mira, prueba así, quite el IF de abajo y le puse un else en su lugar que depende de la función mysql_num_rows()

Comment: nada, sigue sin pintarme los datos, no lo entiendo.

Comment: Bueno, eso es una segunda pregunta que ya no tiene cabida en esta. Si te sirvió la respuesta no te olvides marcar como correcta y si necesitas más ayuda, abre otro hilo con tu problema en específico. Saludos.

Comment: esta en la segunda parte del problema.. Como puedo hacer el rango de fechas para que se pasen ambas al programa en php y este me lo imprima en el excel?

Comment: Le estas pasando 3 parámetros a tu función. La que tu posteaste tiene uno, yo te hice con dos, el tercer parámetro que es? Por eso ni siquiera entra a la función, le faltan datos.

Comment: el tercer parametro es un array llamado $datos, lo que hago es mediante la libreria PHPExcel, le paso los datos que tiene que sacar a un excel  "datos" => obtener_socios(ids_cumplen_anos($datos['desde_fecha_cumple'], $datos['hasta_fecha_cumple'], $datos['opt'])) ; que el desde y el hasta lo coge de los dos inputs iniciales

Comment: "datos" => obtener_socios(ids_cumplen_anos($datos['desde_fecha_cumple'], $datos['hasta_fecha_cumple']), $datos['opt']); Puedo interpretar que es el segundo parámetro de la primera función obtener_socios(id_cumplen_anos(param1,param2),param2)